# GWT/Smart Gwt: Multiple XML file contents to be passed to servlet.

Tags: servlets, gwt

I have the contents of a list of xmls as a string and i need to pass it to server in a hidden variable. I converted a map with fileName as key and value as string, to json to pass it to server. But when i set it in a hidden variable, it doesnt work. If i remove this hidden variable, everything works just fine. I cant use fileUpload since i have the content in a string as the output of a call. I dont want to save the file in server and later download it. Please advise.

```
public void sendFiletoDownload(Map<String, String> result) {

    String jsonResult = JSONUIHelper.toJson(result);
    FormPanel form = new FormPanel();

    _log.logMsg(BsLogLvl.DEBUG, "form.start;"+GWT.getModuleBaseURL());
    form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
    form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
    form.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "dnldSvc");
    _log.logMsg(BsLogLvl.DEBUG, "form.submit();"+StringUtil.makeXMLSafe(jsonResult));
    Hidden hiddenFileName = new Hidden("fileName", "PltAtty.zip");
    Hidden hiddenJSON = new Hidden("jsonData", StringUtil.makeXMLSafe(jsonResult));
    //SafeHTMLUtils.
    form.add(hiddenFileName);
    form.add(hiddenJSON);
    _log.logMsg(BsLogLvl.DEBUG, "form.submit();");
    form.submit();
    _log.logMsg(BsLogLvl.DEBUG, "after submit();");

    form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {

        public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {

            _log.logMsg(BsLogLvl.DEBUG, "after onSubmitComplete;"+event);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i tried couple of options like StringUtil.makeXMLSafe, URL.encode to make sure the hidden variable passes through succesfully... but no success..

Comment: Dropped this approach, although i dont like the alternative. Now going with saving a file in the server and opening the unique id generated in a different window using.. Need to delete the temp files in the directory later.. Window.open(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "dnldSvc?fileName=" + result
          + "&downloadFileName=" + downloadFileName, "_blank", null);